# Could not cast value of type 'UIView' (0x112484eb0) to 'SKView' (0x111646718)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, xcode7, xcode6.3.2

Could not cast value of type 'UIView' (0x112484eb0) to 'SKView' (0x111646718). I keep on getting this error. Can anyone help me because the line of code is there by default. I converted the SK game into the latest swift syntax using the xcode 7 beta. The compiler was missing a lot of things, that is why i came back to xcode 6. I have no red errors; but, the game crashes and says thread 1: signal SIGARBT. Any tips on the changes between swift 2 and the latest version of swift 1 that could have caused problems in the conversion to the latest swift syntax. Perhaps something that was converted, that I should change in xcode 6.3.2. I will delete the beta once this crash issue is resolved. There is probably an error in the code, because i got the same error when i copied the code onto a brand new xcode project.
Thanks in advance!

```
let skView = self.view as! SKView
```

Comment: What is `self` And how is its view property set?. The message is pretty clear - self.view is a UIview, not an SKView.

Comment: the line is pre written. how do i fix the problem?

Comment: It isn't the line that is the problem. It is the configuration of the scene in the storyboard. The scene for this object specifies a UIView for the view outlet, not an SKView

Comment: i don't have any lines of code with sk view except for the defaults!

Comment: It isn't code. It is the storyboard scene

Comment: what should i do with the storyboard?

Comment: As I said above, the view outlet for the class is an instance of a UIView, not an SKView - check the scene, what is the outer most view?  What is its class?

Comment: the class is gameViewController as stated in main.storyboard. Sorry I started this recently. Where do i find the outer most view?

Comment: On your Storyboard, check your GameViewController( *UIViewController) and then click on the empty view. If you go to Identity Inspector (right menu, third icon), you should see Class SKView, but you might have UIView and that is causing the error. Change this class to SKView. - Added an answer with images

Comment: Old question but, *"There is probably an error in the code"* is not helpful **at all**. In what class is this code? What is the type of your controller's view in your storyboard? Are you using a container view? You should make these clear, so that we can reproduce the problem. Also *the line of code is there by default*, by default how? Are you using a template, or sample code, or did you just create a UI element and this was there? Question, hence also your answer, is not clear. That is why there are answers unrelated to what you intended, but are valid because they fix the issue in the title

Comment: I believe you should accept either ArinW. 's or aramusss 's answer, and if you want to, ask the question in more clear terms and post your answer to help others with the same issue, that is if the issue is still reproducable (as the swift language and probably the framework has evolved after this post). E.g: with title "Could not cast value of type 'UIView' to 'SKView' when <your specific case>" and with reproducable steps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not cast value of type 'UIView' to 'SCNView'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35323147/could-not-cast-value-of-type-uiview-to-scnview)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I finally fixed it! Instead of putting the functions in the GameViewController and calling them from game scene, I had to put the functions in gameScene and replace view with self.view!.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be a reasonable solution, but a hack/workaround.

Answer (score 65):

Go to your Storyboard, select your UIViewController that contains the SpriteKit game, and select the view from left menu:

[image]

Now go to Identity Inspector and make sure Class is `SKView` and not `UIView`:

[image]

You should now be able to compile this part of code from your `UIViewController`:

```
// Configure the view.
SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
```

Or in Swift:

```
let skView = self.view as! SKView
```

Comment: what else could it be?

Comment: i made a new xcode project and copied all the code. Still the same error.

Comment: If you create a new Xcode project, select Game, with Swift and (without modifying any code) run the project, do you get the same error? If so, i recommend you to re-install Xcode from scratch (without BETAS, stable version from Apple Store)

Comment: it is stable otherwise. I am using xcode 6.3.2 stabled.

Comment: @Aryaman , did you find a solution? Post it here and accept the answer! :)

Comment: No i couldn't still waiting for it to be resolved. I deleted xcode 7 beta, because it had far more error messages than xcode 6.3.2. I'll have to go through all my code.

Comment: Try uninstalling completely Xcode and reinstall then Xcode 6 from App Store using this command: `sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all`

Comment: No the problem is still there! Something in the code! The code looks all fine to me!

Comment: @Aryaman, after trying this command did you create a new project or run the existing one? Create an existing project, you can't have any error

Comment: made new project. when i add the code, the problem comes again. Nothing to do with skview and uiview just something else. any changes the 'change to latest swift syntax' could have done for a spritekit game?

Comment: thanks for the answer. It was helpful for me. But I also have to UIView object itself to ViewController :/

Answer (score 19):

For those who are not wanting to use a `Storyboard`, you can simple create the view as an `SKView` in the `ViewController`'s `loadView` function.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  override func loadView() {
    self.view = SKView()
  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    let skView = view as! SKView
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple fix. You just have to change the View in which every view controller  your using from UIView to SKView.

Comment: I don't understand why this was downvoted. That actually worked... +1

Comment: Thanks Muhsin. I'm glad this solution helped you as did me!