# Could not cast value of type 'UIView' to 'SCNView'

Tags: ios, scenekit

App was building fine until I started adding buttons to the storyboard then I got the above error. It stops at this line of code inside my GameViewController.

```
let scnView = self.view as! SCNView
```

The storyboard itself has its custom class set to GameViewController (theres no option for SCNView). GameViewController itself inherits from UIViewController.
Im using Xcode7.2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure to also import SceneKit at the top of the file.

```
import SceneKit
```

Open the “Main.storyboard” File. Select ViewController -> View go to “Identity Inspector” and change the Class field to SCNView.
[SceneKit Help](https://www.weheartswift.com/introduction-scenekit-part-1/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I have the `import Scenekit` code in there already, also if I try to change the class field to SCNView Xcode keeps changing it back to GameViewController (as mentioned SCNView is not in the drop down menu) Im beginning to wonder if its a bug with xcode 7.2.

Comment: Change the class of the view, not the view controller

Comment: Don't change the class of the ViewController. Change the class of the View which is in your ViewController.

Answer (score 6):

If you are setting all these stuff programmatically without storyboard, make sure to do these steps:

1. General -> Deployment Info -> Clear the Main Interface section, leave empty.
2. Go to AppDelegate.swift and assign rootViewController of window

```html
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    window = UIWindow()
    let gameViewController = GameViewController()
    window?.rootViewController = gameViewController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

3. Go to GameViewController and here don't cast GameViewController's view to SCNView, instead create SCNView instance and add like subView:

```html
let scnView = SCNView(frame: view.frame)
view.addSubview(scnView)
```

Comment: Thank you!. Only did third step & its worked for me

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this programmatically, add the following code:

```
    override func loadView() {
        //sort of like changes type of self.view from UIView to SCNView
        self.view = SCNView()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me when I deleted a UIButton, which also deleted the UIView. So add a UIView and change class to SCNView