# Trivial modification of storyboard causes crash in XCode

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard, scenekit

I created a brand new project in XCode (12.4).  I chose "Game", which creates a simplistic SCeneKit project.  All fine so far.  Builds and runs, with the little jet aircraft toodling around.

But if I add ANYTHING to the storyboard, for example just a label, the project builds fine, but when started it errors out:

[image]

The view looks like this:

[image]

The error occurs here:

```
   // retrieve the SCNView
    let scnView = self.view as! SCNView
```

This is similar to a problem reported here:

[Could not cast value of type 'UIView' to 'SCNView'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35323147/could-not-cast-value-of-type-uiview-to-scnview)

But as far as I can tell, that problem and mine are different.  Any suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be newbie ignorance on my part.  When XCode constructed the Main view it instantiated a SCNView, which occupied the whole frame of the view.  So when I tried to add a UI control to the view, it REPLACED the SCNView with the UI Control.  So the main code still tried to cast the SCNView to the UIControl.

So the answer is that you can't do that (at least without instantiating another view entirely (as far as I can tell).