# How to bring an SKSprite in front of a storyboard's UI?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, user-interface

I'm having a bit of an issue with a game that I'm currently coding in Swift. Basically, I created all of the UI in a storyboard, with corresponding view controllers for each screen (main menu, settings, store, play, etc etc). In the play view controller, I present an SKScene to handle all of the game logic, along with the storyboard UI. The storyboard UI is working just fine, but I'm trying to create some SKSpriteNodes in the SKScene, and they're spawning behind the main background (defined in the storyboard).

I've already tried manually modifying the SKSpriteNodes' z indexes, but to no avail. If anyone has any idea as to how I could solve this issue, that'd be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add UIView to Storyboard, then define UIView as SKView. You can check how to do it: [Could not cast value of type 'UIView' (0x112484eb0) to 'SKView' (0x111646718)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30792196/could-not-cast-value-of-type-uiview-0x112484eb0-to-skview-0x111646718) Then you will be able present SKScene  inside this SKView.

```
    let skView = self.view as! SKView

    skView.presentScene(GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size))
```